# Multiple receivers on a single method

Tags: go, methods, struct

Is it possible to have multiple receivers on a single function? In other words, a single function can belong to two or more `struct`s?

Say I have

```
type Struct1 struct {
  foo.Client
}

func CreateClient() struct1 {
  return struct1{
    ClientID: cId,
    // ...
  }
}

func (s *Struct1) MyFunc( // ... ) {}
```

But I also want to be able to associate `MyFunc` with another `struct`  (different package):

```
type Struct2 struct {
  lgr log.logger
}

func NewStruct2 (l *log.logger) (*Struct2, err) {
  return &Struct2{mylog: *l}, nil
}
```

So what I want to actually have is:

```
func (s1 *Struct1, s2 *Struct2) MyFunc( // ... ) {}
```

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: What you are asking for doesn’t really make sense. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You can only declare methods on a type in the same package where the type is declared.

Comment: Your best option in this case would be to declare the 2 structs in the same package and have the two receiver methods call a single package function.

Answer (score 5):

*"Is it possible to have multiple receivers on a single function?"* -- It is not possible.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations

> The receiver is specified via an extra parameter section preceding the
> method name. That parameter section **must declare a single non-variadic
> parameter**, the receiver.